# Handle validation of EF in windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I am working with **EF6** to create my model .So i create my **comment** model as you can see here . So for **CommentText** i put **Required**  with its **error message** .When i use MVC ,it works fine and my errors comes and showed ,but i don't know how can i handle this error in **C# win Forms** .I mean when the user leaves the **textbox** as empty the error should be showed .but i don't know how i can access the error message ?

Best regards

```
public partial class Comment
    {
        [DisplayName("شناسه نظر")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "متن نظر را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("متن نظر")]
        public string CommentText { get; set; }


   public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are a MVC feature only. If you wan't this in your Web Forms application, you have to use the RequiredValidator control and set the message in that. You must do that in your aspx or ascx file.

Comment: So you mean i can't use this feature in win form application ?

Comment: Can i set the error message in set property of my model  ?

Comment: That's not true that the validation attributes are for MVC only. They included a built-in mechanism in MVC that is able to display (and include) some data in the View according the to those attributes. If you'll try to call `SaveChanges` upon inserting an invalid entity, you'll get an `DbEntityValidationException` in WinForms as well.

Comment: @haim770 how can i use these validation in win form app ?

Comment: Well it isn't really a MVC feature only. Actually it is system on his own that is introduced with (I thought) RIA Services. MVC is using the attributes. If you want to set the error message in your Winforms control, click the textbox and check the properties. You can set the validation of the textbox there.

Comment: My problem is i don't want to set validation for every textboxs in my application ,i just need to set them once .

Comment: Then you have to create an usercontrol. After that you can set the textbox for your CommentText property once. You then only have to use the usercontrol and bind it to every datasource in the forms.

Comment: But this is more a windows forms problem than MVC. Please add the proper tags to the questions on stackoverlow. Otherwise you will never get a good answer ;-)

Comment: @EA, You can get the list of validation errors using the `DbContext.GetValidationErrors()`. Since i don't know much about WinForms i can't tell you if and how to automatically bind the returned errors to the appropriate Textbox/Label.